# Storing each row of one column as Dictionary value pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm newbie to pandas dataframe and I have a some tricky task to get it done.

I have a dataframe like this.
[image: DataFrame]

Text Format:

SegmentUpper SegmentLower MaterialNumber LowerLimitAVLower LowerLimitAVUpper UpperLimitAVUpper UpperLimitAVLower    RawSegments SiteID  Parameter ParameterDesc

A Upper         A Lower             111             0                   1                   2                   3                   []          2       P1      {'abc':'p1'}

B Upper         B Lower             111             1                   2                   3                   4                   []          2       P1      {'abc':'p1'}

C Upper         C Lower             111             2                   3                   4                   5                   []          2       P1      {'abc':'p1'}

D Upper         D Lower             111             3                   4                   5                   6                   []          2       P1      {'abc':'p1'}

A Upper         A Lower             111             1                   2                   3                   4                   []          2       P2      {'abc':'p2'}

B Upper         B Lower             111             3                   2                   3                   4                   []          2       P2      {'abc':'p2'}

C Upper         C Lower             111             3                   3                   4                   6                   []          2       P2      {'abc':'p2'}

D Upper         D Lower             111             2                   4                   5                   7                   []          2       P2      {'abc':'p2'}

A Upper         A Lower             222             0                   3                   4                   5                   []          2       P1      {'abc':'p1'}

B Upper         B Lower             222             3                   5                   7                   9                   []          2       P1      {'abc':'p1'}

C Upper         C Lower             222             2                   5                   7                   8                   []          2       P1      {'abc':'p1'}

D Upper         D Lower             222             3                   8                   6                   9                   []          2       P1      {'abc':'p1'}

I have to create a new column of type list and store the multiple dictionary values to it.

So basically as in above image I am able to find out way to make column as list, the " **Rawsegment** " column using the below code:

```
DataDF['RawSegment'] = np.empty((len(DataDF), 0)).tolist()
```

Now the tricky part is to add dictionary values to it using the values of other columns in existing Dataframe

For ex:I have a columns called Segment Upper,Segment Lower,LowerLimitAVLower,LowerLimitAVUpper,UpperLimitAVLower,UpperLimitAVLower,MaterialNumber

and i want final output as 
[image: Final DataFrame]

for each material number and parameter Store all A,B,C,D Upper and Lower values as dictionary and retain other columns.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you convert input data sample to text? Because not possible copy your data from picture. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah sure.I added the text format in question itself now please find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column `MaterialNumber` to index and `rename` columns for possible split by `_` for 3 columns `DataFrame` with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then use groupby with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for dictionaries:

```
d = {'SegmentUpper':'Upper_Segment',
     'SegmentLower':'Lower_Segment',
     'LowerLimitAVLower':'Lower_LimitAVLower',
     'LowerLimitAVUpper':'Lower_LimitAVUpper',
     'UpperLimitAVUpper':'Upper_LimitAVUpper',
     'UpperLimitAVLower':'Upper_LimitAVLower'}
df = df.set_index('MaterialNumber').rename(columns=d)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = (df.stack(0)[['Segment','LimitAVLower','LimitAVUpper']]
        .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
        .reset_index(name='RawSegments'))
print (df1)
   MaterialNumber                                        RawSegments
0             111  [{'Segment': 'A Lower', 'LimitAVLower': 0.0, '...
1             222  [{'Segment': 'A Lower', 'LimitAVLower': 0.0, '...
```

Comment: Could you please explain functionality how it is working.

Comment: and also if i have to keep remaining columns which are already present in Dataframe what i have to do?

Comment: @sindhu - Sorry, can you explain more?

Comment: meaning suppose I have SiteID,ParameterDict columns also along with what ever  I have mentioned above and i want to keep that in final dataframe then what I have to do? It would be great if you explain your answer (functionality).

Comment: @sindhu - OK, I try. Main idea is create 3 column DataFrame - each pair join together. So all columns without `Upper/Lower` are converted to index (df.set_index('MaterialNumber'), if necessary more columns use `df.set_index(['MaterialNumber','another col'])`) and then add `_` to columns anmes for possible split by `_`. So is possible use `stack(0)` which return 3 columns. Explanation is OK? Or something is necessary explain more?

Comment: Yeah got your explanation and i will go through more about stack functionality. Now your answer will result in 3 columns dataframe but if i want to keep other remaining columns also for ex SiteID which is not index in final Dataframe then what has to be done? Basically final dataframe should have 3+1 columns

Comment: @sindhu - Can you change data with this column with expected output?

Comment: @sindhu - It seems you forget for columns `SideId` and `Parameter` in input sample data.

Comment: Changed the output and input as well.Sorry for inconvience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182762/discussion-between-sindhu-and-jezrael).